# tkinter, button returns variable

Tags: python-3.x, variables, button, tkinter, return

I am trying to make a GUI text based adventure game in python. I want to be able to take text from a textinput box and store it as string variable.

I have 2 problems:

1. Making the python wait for the submit button to be pressed, before
   processing the input and updating the game.
2. Getting the text variable out of the command, I would like to not
   use global if possible.

Here is some of my code to better understand:

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('800x600+100+100')
root.title("my game")
textbox = tk.StringVar()
textboxentry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=textbox, bd=5, width = "40",  font=("times", 20))
textboxentry.pack(in_=bgImageLabel, side = "bottom")
def getInput():
    textboxInput = textbox.get() #gets entry
    lengthEntry = len(textbox.get())
    textboxentry.delete(0,lengthEntry) #removes entry from widget
    return textboxInput # I would like this return to work 


submit = tk.Button(root, text ="Submit", command = (textboxInput = getInput()))
##I want the command function to use command = getInput and store the return on getInput as textboxInput. This will update the wait_variable down below, and give the inputs(textboxInput) a string to work with.

submit.pack(in_=bgImageLabel, side = "bottom")

while game == True:
    root.update_idletasks()
    root.update()
    submit.wait_variable(textboxentry)   
## I need it to wait before proceeding to this next line because i need the textboxInput from the entry widget.
    actionInput, extraInput, texts = inputs(textboxInput)
```

Currently I can't figure a way to use `command = (textboxInput = getInput)`, using lambda or anything else. I just want to store the return which comes off of the Entry as a string variable that can be used by the `main` function.
All help is appreciated!

Comment: I could use global on textboxInput in the program, but then the issue is how do I get my program to wait for an input before trying to run inputs(textboxInput)?

Comment: Are you aware the tkinter has it's own 'infinite' loop on which it runs when showing the windows and handling events? Right now it seems like your `while` loop will prevent the windows to show up.

Comment: The functions you use as button commands should rather _modify_ values instead of returning values, since they return to somewhere isn't being listened to, practically unusable.

Comment: In its current state your question demands an example rather than a fix.

Comment: use `inputs(textboxInput)` inside `getInput()` and then button will not have to return any variable and you could use `root.mainloop()` instead of your `while loop`

Answer (score 1):

Below code processes entry widget's text when Submit button is pressed.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

aVarOutside = 'asd'
def btn_cmd(obj):

    #use global variable
    global aVarOutside
    #print its unmodified value
    print("aVarOutside: " + aVarOutside)
    #modify it with what's written in Entry widget
    aVarOutside = obj.get()

    #modify lblTextVar, which is essentially modifying Label's text as lblTextVar is its textvariable
    lblTextVar.set(obj.get())

    #print what's inside Entry
    print("Entry: " + obj.get())

txt = tk.Entry(root)
txt.pack()

lblTextVar = tk.StringVar()
lbl = tk.Label(root, textvariable=lblTextVar)
lbl.pack()

btn = tk.Button(text="Submit", command=lambda obj = txt : btn_cmd(obj))
btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

**When the button is pressed:**

1. Value of a global variable, `aVarOutside` is printed.
2. Value of `aVarOutside` is *modified* to the value of Entry box's
   (`txt`'s) content.
3. Value of a textvariable used by a label (`lbl`) is *modified*. Which
   means that the text of `lbl` is updated and can be seen on the GUI.
4. Finally Entry box, `txt`'s content is printed.

Comment: I cant use root.mainloop() because it wouldnt run the last line "inputs(textboxentry)" so I have a while loop with root.updateidletasks and root.update.This works just fine and allows that final line and any other lines I want to add to run before the loop finishes and the window is refreshed.

Comment: In your example, can I use btn.wait_variable(obj)? It seems like you are passing in txt as obj to the btn_cmd, but I dont think this updates any variable that can be checked for by wait_variable()

Comment: @TraggThorsgard Not sure I follow what you're saying. I do pass `txt` object as the argument to `btn_cmd`.

Comment: if you could give an example where instead of printing obj.get() obj.get is saved to a variable that could be used outside of btn_cmd. normally you would use return but lambda doesnt allow you to run "btn_cmd" like "variable = btn_cmd()"

Comment: @TraggThorsgard Updated my answer to better reflect what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `inputs()` inside `getInputs()` and then `button` doesn't have to return any variables - and then you can use `root.mainloop()` instead of `while` loop.

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

def inputs(text):
    # do something with text 
    print(text)

    # and return something      
    return 'a', 'b', 'c'

def get_input():
    global action_input, extra_input, texts

    text = textbox.get()

    if text: # check if text is not empty
        textbox.set('') # remove text from entry
        #textbox_entry.delete(0, 'end') # remove text from entry
        action_input, extra_input, texts = inputs(text)

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

textbox = tk.StringVar()

textbox_entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=textbox)
textbox_entry.pack()

submit = tk.Button(root, text="Submit", command=get_input)
submit.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

---

BTW: you could better organize code

- all functions before main part (`root = tk.Tk()`)
- [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) suggests to use `lower_case_names` for functions and variables (instead of `CamelCaseNames`)

---

`global` is not prefered method but I think it is better solution than yours.

If you don't need `global` then you can use classes with `self.`

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- classes ---

class Game:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()

        self.textbox = tk.StringVar()

        self.textbox_entry = tk.Entry(self.root, textvariable=self.textbox)
        self.textbox_entry.pack()

        self.submit = tk.Button(self.root, text="Submit", command=self.get_input)
        self.submit.pack()

    def run(self):
        self.root.mainloop()

    def inputs(self, text):
        # do something with text 
        print(text)

        # and return something      
        return 'a', 'b', 'c'

    def get_input(self):

        text = self.textbox.get()

        if text: # check if text is not empty
            self.textbox.set('') # remove text from entry
            #textbox_entry.delete(0, 'end') # remove text from entry
            self.action_input, self.extra_input, self.texts = self.inputs(text)

# --- functions ---

# empty


# --- main ---

app = Game()
app.run()
```